# Image No Stretch or crop

Tags: css, image, stretch

My question is simple. Let's say I have two rectangular images. The first is 200px wide and 100px tall, and the second is 100px wide and 200px tall.

I want to display the images with a constant width/height, e.g. 150px by 150px without stretching the images to fit:

[image]

I don't mind having whitespace/padding around the images. The problem is that the images could be of any width and height, and I want to limit them to a square box without stretching them.

The following CSS stretches the images to fit to 150px by 150px:

```
img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

The most preferable solution is CSS, even if I need a little more markup. JS/jQuery is okay as well though.

Comment: Do you want the image to increase to 150px if it is smaller than the box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
img {
    max-height:150px;
    max-width:150px
}
```

To achieve your 2nd question on making smaller images bigger, you can do with jQuery. CSS could work if you knew the photo orientation before hand and applied a different css class to those images... But this will work and then you don't need the CSS max-width stuff any more.

```
<div class="container"><img src="images/DSC_0470.JPG" alt="Rad Image" /></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('.container img').each(
            function () {
                var theWidth = $(this).width();
                var theHeight = $(this).height();
                if (theWidth < theHeight) {
                    $(this).height(150);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).width(150);
                }

            });
        });</script>
```

Comment: +1, first 1 to answer correctly...but be sure next time you present your answer, atleast edit after you answer, provide relative reference links, code, and if you can than a fiddle too as a demo :)

Comment: Presentation of your answer matters!

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that an image smaller than 150px by 150px fills the space?

Comment: I don't think so purely with CSS unless you knew the orientation and could apply the right class to it. Have you tried a JS approach?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `max-width` and `max-height` properties, like so:

```
img {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

This should constrain it to that box without stretching it.

If you want to make sure that each appears in a square box of size `150px` by `150px`, you could contain each image in a container div, and force them to be exactly that size:

```
<div class="container">
  <img>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
.container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Does this solution not work in IE8, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -4):

Try this format...

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="border:none;position:absolute; top:20px; left:50px; width:100px; height:200px;">
```