# Setting image without cropping and stretching

Tags: html, css

I want to set image in img tag, without cropping it or stretching it.
That is, the image ratio I have set is 1:1 but image may vary in aspect ratio, so I neither want to change the aspect ratio nor want to crop it vertically or horizontally. my images are changing dynamically.

I have checked multiple solutions for eg: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733006/css-force-image-width-and-height-without-stretching) which suggests either crop height or width. But I don't want both.

Currently I am at this:
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="imgHolder" />
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#container{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #imgHolder{
        height: 100%;
        /* OR width: 100%; */
    }
```

Help. I prefer CSS only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image No Stretch or crop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333699/image-no-stretch-or-crop)

Comment: @Paulie_D why javascript?

Comment: if you don't want both, you can set a max-height and / or max-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just set both the `max-width` and the `max-height` of your images

```
#container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Doing so the image won't be stretched since your not changing its `width` or `height`: whatever is the image size, setting the above properties together ensures that the longest side is reduced to the maximum width (or height) of its parent `div`, while the other one can freely adapt itself, keeping the original image ratio.

Example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEjLZa

---

Example with centered images (both ver. and hor.): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPgege

Comment: remove the height in your code and use this. See the example

Comment: Thank You.. Now a extra query, can I assign it to center?

Comment: I think my second example has anticipated your question :)

Comment: I placed the html code in body and css in script, bt its not working on chrome or Mozilla. but working in JSFiddle or codePen. just help last time.

Comment: without a real example that shows your specific issue I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69621/discussion-between-surajs-and-fabrizio-calderan).

Answer (score 0):

If you set a height and width on the parent container, it is hard to retain a perfect aspect ratio without stretching or cropping the image.  If the image is the same size, 100px x 100px then you could use

CSS

```
#container{ position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; }

img{ 
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  }
```

This will set the image to cover the parent container.  You could also try

```
img {
  background: url( yourimage.png) cetner no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

This will set the image to fill the larger of the dimensions to the parent container and will center it.  The smaller dimension will not be covered, but it will retain is apsect ratio.