# CSS working in codePen but not in actual browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I got a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154002/setting-image-without-cropping-and-stretching) which is in Codepen.
Here it is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPgege

but when I created a HTML file as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
   background-color: #ccc;
   margin: 20px;
}

 .container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x150/000/fff" />
</div>

<div class="container">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x100/000/fff" />
</div>

<div class="container">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

although having same code, its not giving the same output
Help.

Comment: Well what are you getting? How about a screenshot?

Comment: @j08691 or copy the tiny amount of code into your own html file and see for yourself?

Comment: U've forgotten `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache?  ctrl+f5 a couple times?

Comment: It was <!DOCTYPE html> only.. Didnt know it changes the output this much..!

Comment: Pages without the doctype are sometimes rendered differently (in quirks mode)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue: as @user3790069 mentioned, browsers use different CSS by default depending on whether a doctype is declared.

Code on Codepen automatically uses an HTML 5 doctype, **unless your document starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` you will be missing some of the styles you can see on codepen.**